# Is the average of positive-definite matrices also positive-definite?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matrix, covariance-matrix

Is the average of multiple positive-definite matrices necessarily positive-definite or positive semi-definite? The average is element-wise average.

Comment: Average is just sum followed by scaling. Is this true for each of those?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is. jth asnwer is correct (+1) but I think you can get a much simple explanation with just basic Linear Algebra.

Assume $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices for size $n$. By definition this means that for all $u \in R^n$, $0 < u^TAu$ and $0 < u^TBu$. 
This means that $0 < u^TAu + u^TBu$ or equivalently that $ 0 < u^T(A+B)u$. ie. $(A+B)$ has to be positive definite.

Answer (score 15):

Of course. The set of positive definite matrices [forms a cone](http://www.convexoptimization.com/wikimization/index.php/Positive_semidefinite_cone), meaning it is closed under positive linear combinations and scaling.